How to read the content of a .db file in R?
This is the first time I am trying to load this type of file in R and for whatever reason it's been quite challenging.
The data I am using can be found here.
So, I am following instructions from a book that teaches about survey data, and the book uses this data as example. However, there are no instructions about how to load the data in R. The data is in SQLite format, which is a bit odd to me.
With a little research I came into this post, which was the closest to my problem. When I try to apply the code provided I run into error.
library(RSQLite)
filename <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname = 'imp.db')

sqlite.driver <- dbDriver("SQLite")
db <- dbConnect(sqlite.driver,
                dbname = filename)

And I run into the following error:
Error in as.character.default(x) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(dbname) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'S4'

All I wanna do is to load the content as a data.frame or any other format that is used in R. Can someone help me?

Seems like a typo. you should not be specifying the dbname multiple times. Try just db <- dbConnect(drv=SQLite(), dbname='imp.db') and get rid of the filename and sqlite.driver values. Currently you pass dbname = filename to  dbConnect but you defined filename to be a dbConnect object itself rather than just the path to the file you want to read


Next, I try to run the code test <- svydesign(id=~SDPPSUG, + strat = ~SDPSTRAG, + weigh = ~WTPFQXG, + nest = T, + data = db)

From ?survey::svydesign:

data may be a character string giving the name of a table or view in a relational database that can be accessed through the DBI interfaces. For DBI interfaces dbtype should be the name of the database driver and dbname should be the name by which the driver identifies the specific database (eg file name for SQLite).

Based on the database example from svydesign documentation, you could try:
library(survey, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
#> Loading required package: grid
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> Loading required package: survival
library(RSQLite)

test <- svydesign(id=~SDPPSU6, strat = ~SDPSTRA6, weight = ~WTPFQX6, nest = TRUE, 
                  data = "set1", dbtype="SQLite", dbname = "imp.db") 
test
#> DB-backed Stratified 1 - level Cluster Sampling design (with replacement)
#> With (98) clusters.
#> svydesign(id = ~SDPPSU6, strat = ~SDPSTRA6, weight = ~WTPFQX6, 
#>     nest = TRUE, data = "set1", dbtype = "SQLite", dbname = "imp.db")
close(test)

Created on 2024-09-21 with reprex v2.1.1

library(RSQLite)
filename <- "/path/to/file/imp.db"
sqlite.driver <- dbDriver("SQLite")
db <- dbConnect(sqlite.driver,dbname = filename)
readindb <- dbReadTable(db,"core")
head(readindb, 6)

Table has a lot of info, can't display all columns. Now you can access all the data through the variable that I named 'readindb'

used this link for help
